# Launch chrome application on startup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I would like to open a packaged chrome application automatically when the browser starts.
I have tried: chrome-extension://app id/
But it doesn't work. I get chrome-extension://invalid/ error page.

Comment: [chrome.management.launchApp(id)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-launchApp)

Comment: where exactly would I run this? I can't include it in the app as it's a packaged app and management is not allowed

Comment: If you control the app why dont you just open it normally?

Comment: End users can't be trusted to remember to run the app. So I want it to run as soon as the browser opens up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the chrome.runtime.onStartup event, "Fired when a profile that has this extension installed first starts up".

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
 chrome.app.window.create("main.html")
})
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup

Comment: This is the right answer, but it doesn't seem to work on Chrome 68; at least not with an unpacked extension.